# How can I use grep with a date format and a unique value?

Tags: linux, grep

i have huge data list

My data looks like this

```
"[01/Dec/2011:20:53:04 +0900] ","COMZ","90.663.65.61","21.123.31.100","250","CONNECT","t.ierz.er:443","13127","836"
"[01/Dec/2011:22:20:01 +0900] ","COMZ","90.663.65.61","21.123.31.100","250","CONNECT","t.ierz.er:443","13127","836"
"[02/Dec/2011:24:33:04 +0900] ","COMZ","20.663.65.61","2.123.91.100","220","CONNECT","t.ierz.er:443","13127","836"
```

How can I get a data format like unique value data or IP address

```
01/DEC/2011 90.663.65.61 21.123.31.100
```

Because I have get the same value and cant get the unique value

```
[01 / Dec / 2011: 20: 53: 04 0900] 90.663.65.61 21.123.31.100
[01 / Dec / 2011: 20: 53: 04 0900] 90.663.65.61 21.123.31.100
```

code:

```
file.csv | awk -F\" '{print $2,$6,$8}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: can you share few more lines in examples data?

Comment: You probably want `uniq -u`? Also, it's not clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish. So you want to see unique IPs and unique dates?

Comment: yes Unique IP address with date
Because the seconds in that date format are different so cant get uniq values

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 awk -F '[:"[]' '{print $3" "$10" "$12}' file.csv | sort | uniq
```

Comment: That's better. but you should include the commands that were first there. `uniq -c | sort -n`.

Comment: @jayooin does it required?  I hope...OP's requirement is to get the unique value rather than its count...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sed` to complete your request.

Here is a command that should work for your case :

```
 cat file.csv | awk -F\" '{print $2,$6,$8}' | sed 's#\(:[[:digit:]]\{2\}\)\{3\} +0900##' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

It will remove the date to keep only this format : `[01/DEC/2011] 90.663.65.61 21.123.31.100`.

Answer (score 1):

As your data seems to be in CSV format you might be able to use `csvsql` from `csvkit`, see https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.3/scripts/csvsql.html#

Assuming your file is named `data.csv`

```
csvsql -H --query 'SELECT a,c,d FROM data GROUP BY c,d' data.csv
```

prints

```
a,c,d
[02/Dec/2011:24:33:04 +0900] ,20.663.65.61,2.123.91.100
[01/Dec/2011:22:20:01 +0900] ,90.663.65.61,21.123.31.100
```

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495010/330217

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend using a CSV parser for CSV data. Here's ruby:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne 'CSV.parse($_) do |row|
  puts [row[0][1..11].upcase, row[2], row[3]].join " "
end' | sort -u
```

```
01/DEC/2011 90.663.65.61 21.123.31.100
02/DEC/2011 20.663.65.61 2.123.91.100
```